# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar useEffect si cambia algún valor del state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo a usar los hooks y tengo un estado que cambia cada rato cuando el usuario hace una acción. Mi código es éste:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [ /* Es vacio por que se creaba un bucle infinito */ ]);

// Y si coloco un fetchData() nuevamente se me crea un bucle infinito
```

Mi intención es que cada que vez que mi estado global se actualice, se ejecute nuevamente el `useEffect`, lo podría hacer haciendo un `onClick`, pero son varios botones y submit que toca configurar. ¿Hay alguna manera para que `useEffect` se ejecute por cada cambio del state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que se ejecute solo cuando cambia un state tienes que hacer esto:

```
const [state, setState] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
}, state);
```

**Resumen:**

- Si quieres ejecutar un efecto y sanearlo solamente una vez (al montar
  y desmontar), puedes pasar un array vacío ([]) como segundo argumento
- Si quieres que se ejecute en cada renderizado no pongas nada
- Si quieres que se ejecute cuando un elemento cambie, pasalo como
  segundo parámetro

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Ya estaba por borrar la pub por que ya lo habia hecho, lo hice de tal manera, mucha gracias!

Comment: Pero lo que hice fue crear un state local,  y  comparo state local con el state global y si hay cambio ejecuto otra vez fetchData